# parabolic_squaremesh not defined in DifferentialEquations

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I'm trying to reproduce an example from a tutorial and I get stuck with meshes not being defined:

```
using DiffEqBase 
using DiffEqPDEBase
f(t,x,u)  = ones(size(x,1)) - .5u
u0_func(x) = zeros(size(x,1))
tspan = (0.0,1.0)
dx = 1//2^(3)
dt = 1//2^(7)
# THE FOLLOWING LINE IS FAILING
mesh = parabolic_squaremesh([0 1 0 1],dx,dt,tspan,:neumann)
u0 = u0_func(mesh.node)
prob = HeatProblem(u0,f,mesh)
sol = solve(prob,FEMDiffEqHeatImplicitEuler())
```

The code fails at the line where I try to create the mesh with the error message:
*UndefVarError: parabolic_squaremesh not defined
top-level scope at test.jl:22
All packages are installed without errors. However, I was not able to install the 
*using FiniteElementDiffEq* which seems to be depreciated.

Comment: That tutorial hasn't existed since like 2017. Those functions don't exist. I'm not sure how you found it.

Comment: Yes, I started to understand the system better. It looks like the mesh functions have been in old versions of differential equations of Julia but have been discontinued. I was after a google search directed to version juliadiffeq (and did not realize to shift to the new version of the manual)
http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/v3.0.0/features/mesh.html

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has not existed in many years. It was found because of a Google search turning up DifferentialEquations.jl v3.0, while v6.0 is the first version to support Julia 1.0. There's not much else to say about this other than you won't make it work on a modern version of Julia, and if you want to use it you'd have to drop back to something like Julia v0.6.